# Why has Ubuntu minor version number 04 or 10 only?

Tags: ubuntu, version, releases

Why if an Ubuntu with a new major version is to be released the minor version is automatically 04 (and 10) for updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Ubuntu is usually released in April (4th month) and October (10th month).

The Version number also indicates the year of the release - therefore the first released version of Ubuntu was Ubuntu 4.10 (20th October 2004).

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases):

> Ubuntu releases are made semiannually by Canonical Ltd, the developers
>   of the Ubuntu operating system, using the year and month of the
>   release as a version number. The first Ubuntu release, for example,
>   was Ubuntu 4.10 and was released on 20 October 2004.
>
> Consequently, version numbers for future versions are provisional; if
>   the release is delayed until a different month (or even year) to that
>   planned, the version number changes accordingly.

Comment: That was an interesting fact to know about Ubuntu